Using a Potentiometer to consecutively turn on 4 LEDs one at a time, while turning off the all LEDs before it
I'm not quite sure the simplest way to describe this and I'm only using LEDs as my example because it's the easiest way to simplify my circuit. I need to use 1 potentiometer to turn on 1 LED, then as it further decreases/increases in resistance a second LED turns on, and the original turns off, same goes for the 3rd LED, it should turn on and the 2 previous should be off, etc, etc for 4, 5 or more LEDs. I've tried working this with a variety of different comparator circuits and even some MOSFET logic but I'm struggling with finding the correct way to get the previous LEDs off.
A visualization of this would be the following:
1000
0100
0010
0001
Edit: I missed a huge part I should have specified, I'm limited to Op-Amps, Comparators and MOSFETS for this problem.

I have rolled back your question, because there were already answers, and your edit invalidated those answers.

A bargraph driver that has a dot mode like a 3914 is purpose-built for this application; @Ben_Voigt had an elegant solution using multiple opamps here: How can I light only one LED at a time depending on voltage input? but it would probably be easier to use a single chip if you're trying to drive more than three or four LEDs.

Basic idea

I'm struggling with finding the correct way to get the previous LEDs off.

There is such a way which is based on the following phenomenon:
If you connect two LEDs (Zener diodes) with different threshold voltages in parallel, the current will flow through the LED with the lower voltage which will light up, and the other one will turn off. A simple explanation of this current behavior is that it (like humans:-) chooses the path of least resistance. A slightly more complicated explanation is that the two LEDs behave like dynamic resistors that vigorously change their resistances in the opposite direction.
Conceptual circuit
We usually have LEDs of the same type with the same threshold voltage. Then we can artificially "raise" the voltage of one of them (LED1 in the schematic below) by connecting a diode D1 in series.
SW = OFF: When the switch is open, the total voltage across the LED1-D1 network is 2.6 V, and the current flows through LED1.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
SW = ON: When the switch is closed, the common voltage  is 1.9 V, and the current is diverted (steered) through LED2. The common voltage VD slightly decreases (with 0.7 V), and the common current through R5 increases.

simulate this circuit
Further development of the idea
We can continue to connect more and more LEDs with gradually decreasing threshold voltage in parallel, and only one of them - the one with the lowest voltage - will light up. This is what the OP needs.
A bit of history
This idea of ​​this "multi-LED indicator" came to me in the early 80's when I had already invented its simpler but very useful "3-LED version". Then I failed to get a patent for it because an older colleague of mine (be opposed to new ideas) from the neighboring lab at the university had given a negative review to the patent office. So in 1983, I published an article  in the magazine Radio, Television, Electronics (in Bulgarian).
This was 40 years ago, but now looking at @Spehro's schematic, I realized that this is the same circuit with  transistors replaced by open collector comparators ("ideal transistors" with zero Vbe voltage)!
Transistor implementation
So, the transistors act as "open collector comparators" (the base-emitter junction is the input, and the collector-emitter part the output). As the input voltage increases, they saturate one after the other and connect the next LED (with a lower threshold voltage) in parallel with the previous diode strings.

simulate this circuit
As you can see from the graphs below, the currents crossfade.

Step-by-step operation
Let's see how this happens in five steps illustrated by equivalent circuit diagrams:
Vin <= 700 mV: All transistors are off; LED1 is on.

simulate this circuit
Vin = 800 mV: Only Q1 is on; LED2 is on.

simulate this circuit
Vin = 900 mV: Both Q1 and Q2 are on; LED3 is on.

simulate this circuit
Vin = 1 V: Q1, Q2 and Q3 are on; LED4 is on.

simulate this circuit
Vin => 1.1 V: All transistors are on; LED5 is on.

simulate this circuit
Conclusions

The transistor and comparator implementations are based on the same current steering idea.

This is another confirmation that ideas do not get old, only their implementations do.

The transistor configuration is more imprecise than the comparator one.

It reveals the idea at a lower level.

The light spot smoothly moves (crossfages) which may be desirable.

Both circuits should be supplied by a relatively constant current source since the voltage across the diode network varies with 0.7 V at each step.



Here is a way that you can use an antediluvian LM339 quad comparator and a handful of other parts:

The open-drain comparator outputs go low in sequence, and steal the constant current away from the previous LEDs by virtue of the 1N4148 diodes providing a bit of voltage drop each. The LEDs have to be red color for this to work with a 5V supply. You'd need a bit higher supply voltage for blue or white LEDs. It should also be noted that the input common mode range of the LM339 does not support the design working reliably exactly as shown, so the R5 should be higher to keep the maximum input voltage for comparison less than 2V below the positive supply. As long as one of the two inputs is within the common-mode range then the comparator output will be valid, so the input voltage can go to more than 30V for this particular chip, even with a 5V supply.
But in 2024 I would use something like a CH552E MCU in MSOP-10 package plus a resistor, plus a USB socket and momentary switch for programming (latter two could be off-board). Plus the 4x LEDs, of course.

Nice solution! It would be interesting to me to know the origin of this circuit solution.

I guess I'll turn out to be the inventor of the circuit :-)

@Circuitfantasist I don't think it has any particular origin that I can recall, just a combination of a few more-or-less obvious building blocks. But the description in your answer is useful.

National Semiconductor has the perfect part for you, the LM3914.  It has both a dot mode and bar graph mode; dot mode is what you want.  10 outputs, evenly spaced in input voltage increments.  And, the output stages are constant-current LED drivers.  This is a great part, and has been around for decades.
See: Texas Instruments LM3914 datasheet

It's a great part but it's being discontinued :(
